# Inflate custom view in fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-view, android-custom-view

I need to implement custom view in Fragment. So far I have accomplished to extend View class to draw on canvas and set it to activity following [google example](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html).

I would like to draw on canvas in fragment and problem is that I do not know how to inflate the view, because it is object but not xml file.

```
 return inflater.inflate(R.layout.article_view, container, false);
```

Can somebody help me to understand and solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As simple as this:

```
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return new YourCustomView(container.getContext());
    }
```